# Printing angular component in a totally different format (view)

Tags: angular, printing, html-table, printing-web-page

I have list of processes in my component in a grid format like so

```
<grid #grid [dataSourceCallback]="getList" type="simple">
    <ng-template let-process="row">             
        <ws-process-item [process]="process" type="full"></ws-process-item>
    </ng-template>
</grid>
```

but i need to print this list in a table format, like this

```
<ng-template let-process="row">
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <th class="col-1">{{ process.id }}</th> 
        <th class="col-2">{{ process.title }}</th>
        <th class="col-2">{{ process.description }}</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

i've tried to hide the code below and show it when printing but it's not a robust solution.
Someone suggested me create temporary viewref for printing in a table format but i couldn't get 
it working, is it a good idea? Or are there any solutions better than that?

Answer (score 0):

came out with different component for printing calling it with viewRef

```
    onPrint()
    {       
        this.viewRef = this.appDisplayService.rootViewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.printerTemplate);       
    }
```

after printing  need to remove it from the view

```
this.viewRef.destroy();
```